# Узнать HWND окна

Tags: winapi, delphi

Здравствуйте, уважаемые Delphi знатоки!
Вопрос следующий - есть `MDI` окно, оно скрыто `ShowWndow(hwnd,SW_HIDE)`, есть его имя, как узнать его `HWND`.

Comment: в поставке делфи есть spyxx.exe (имя может  немного отличатся). Запустите его и посмотрите, видит ли он это скрытое окно. Если да, тогда найти его можно будет. Если не - тогда будет сложно.

Comment: Да spy видит его

Comment: скорее всего нужно будет делать так: вначале с помощью findwindow найти родительское окно, а потом с помощью findwindowex найти уже дочернее.